# Let $A$ be a local ring, $M$ and $N$ finitely generated $A$ modules. Prove that if $M \otimes N = 0,$ then $M = 0$ or $N = 0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Here is the question I am trying to solve:\

Let $A$ be a local ring, $M$ and $N$ finitely generated $A$ modules. Prove that if $M \otimes N = 0,$ then $M = 0$ or $N = 0.$

Here is an answer to it:

> [image]

But I have some questions on the solution:

1- Why are scalar extensions vector spaces? is there a proof for this?

2- How scalar extensions are vector spaces leads to $M \otimes N = 0$ implies that $(M \otimes N)_k = 0$?

3- I know that $(M \oplus N) \otimes P = (M \otimes P) \oplus (N \otimes P),$ but why this is correct if instead of $\oplus$ we have $\otimes$ also?

Could anyone explain these issues to me please?

**EDIT:**

The red writing referring to propositions in Atiyah and MacDonald "Introduction to commutative algebra"

Comment: Well, it seems that if we could have this red references fresh we could help

Comment: @janmarqz it is referring to Atiyah and MacDonald "Introduction to commutative algebra"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A vector space is a module with an action by a field of scalars. $k$ is a field, since any ring modulo a maximal ideal is a field. And $k\otimes_A M$ has an obvious $k$-action given by $k\cdot(k'\otimes m) = (kk')\otimes m$, hence it is a vector space.
2. Well this argument is explicitly shown in your text, in the screencap you shared. Since $M\otimes N$ is zero (by hypothesis), therefore also $k\otimes(M\otimes N)$ is zero. One of the steps in the argument is referring back to formula 2.14.
3. This isn't a distributivity identity. It's not generally true that $(M\otimes N)\otimes P = (M\otimes P)\otimes (N\otimes P)$. However if $P$ is the module of scalars $A$, then we have $A\otimes_A A\cong A$, and so if we have many factors tensored, we can collapse them all to a single one. $k$ is a quotient of $A$ and a similar logic applies.